# How to copy value of custom field/property to another custom field/property of database-bean?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, nhibernate-mapping

i need following things but unfortunately i am unable to do it, 
can any one help then appreciate....!!!

**NOTE :** *classANumber*, *classABNumber* both field is not available into Database - it's custom field for our bean.

ABC.hbm.xml

```
<property name="classANumber" lazy="false" type="java.lang.String" formula="(select ac.classNumber from accessClass ac)"/>

<property name="classABNumber" lazy="false" type="java.lang.String" formula="(select abc.classNumber from accessBothClass abc where ac.classCombileNumber = classANumber)"/>
```

Above is my .hbm.xml file configuration.

Actually, I want to use value of '**classANumber**' property into another custom-field's value searching query.